# Minimal Normal Subgroups of an elementary abelian p-group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, p-groups

> Can you explain/prove, why the number of minimal normal subgroups of an elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^n$ (for instance of $\mathbb{Z_p}^n$), is exactly $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$?

I know that it seems trivial but i can't see why. It is an exercise from Dixon & Mortimer book "Permutation Groups" pg.120.

Comment: A minimal normal subgroup here is the same as a subgroup of order $p$, so count the number of elements of order $p$ and divide by the number of elements of order $p$ in such a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for your response! A subgroup of order $p$ however is always of the form $0 \times 0 \times... \times \mathbb{Z}_p  \times ... \times 0$, isn't it?

Comment: No, try to see what some element not of that form generates.

Comment: You are absolutely right again. Thank you very much.. It was easy!